# Evaluate if Variable Name is equals to String

Tags: javascript

I have

```
var myArrayVariable1 = new Array();
var myStringVariable1 = 'myArrayVariable1';
var myStringVariable2 = 'myArrayVariable2';
```

Is there any way to figure out if one of the strings match the variables name? In case above, `myStringVariable1.Value = myArrayVariable1.VariablesName`

My conundrum:
I have around 100 objects that are unique to each user.
I need to update each object each minute

Each object is named as the database id; javascript would have to locate the object, delete it and then re-create it using new values (these are pulled via json)

So I need to locate the object (using the string that I have gotten from the json), then I need somehow call that object to delete it... 
kind of stuck here.

In **abstract** I am looking for something like this:

```
foreach(object obj in allObjects){
  if (obj.ActualName==="something"){
   obj.Delete();
 }
}
```

After some thinking, and no answer to my question, I am thinking about using some sort of dictionary (a hashmap equivalent) to track all the objects

Comment: could you give me a complete code?

Comment: There is no way to get the variable name and also no point in doing so since you have to write it's name in order to compare it with anything.

Comment: In any circumstance where you have to refer to myArrayVariable1, you will have to type out `myArrayVariable1`, because nothing points to a reference.

Comment: I provided more details about my problem

Comment: see : http://jsfiddle.net/cpmpK/

Comment: I'm guessing that whatever you're doing, isn't the best coding practice of dynamic languages. You're creating objects that you don't even know their names, and then trying to find out what they're names are. Don't you know - Eval is Evil! (and all the other stuff that goes along with it...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the variable is part of an object, you can traverse on it :

```
var obj {
    myVar: 'hello'
};
for (var varName in obj) {
    alert(varName + ' = ' + obj[varName]);
}
```

Comment: I added some abstract function